# Web SQL Delete Query not Working

Tags: javascript, sql, database, cordova, web-sql

i am writing a code for cordova app to delete all data from Web SQL DB table on function call.

Here is the code

```
function removeitem(){
db.transaction(function (tx) {
tx.executeSql("DELETE FROM hist", [], function (tx, result) {
toast('Deleted');
}, function (error) {
        alert(error.code);
}); 

}, function (error) {
        alert(error);
    });

}
```

But the code doesn't work and always give alert

> [Object SQLError]

Other functions for creating table, updating records are working fine but delete query is creating problem. Please help guys to identify the problem.

THANKS

Comment: Try using "DELETE FROM hist" on actual database to check.

Comment: @AslanShemilov it does work when i do it that way.

Comment: Have you already tried this statement: DELETE FROM hist WHERE ..... you have to have a where-condition.

Comment: You must have WHERE unless you want to empty whole table.

Comment: Can you try at least "DELETE FROM hist WHERE 1"

Comment: @AslanShemilov It's not working with where clause and i would like to inform that db.transaction block is giving error code 0

Comment: As long as you want to delete all data from table, try below statement: "TRUNCATE TABLE hist"

Answer (score 0):

As long as you want to delete all data from table, try below statement:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE hist;

tx.executeSql("TRUNCATE TABLE hist",[], 
    function(tx,results){console.log("Successfully Emptied")},
    function(tx,error){console.log("Could not Empty")}
);
```

or

```
tx.executeSql("DELETE FROM hist",[], 
    function(tx,results){console.log("Successfully Emptied");},
    function(tx,error){console.log("Could not Empty");}
);
```

One of them must work.

Full code:

```
var db.transaction(function (tx) {
     tx.executeSql("DELETE FROM hist",[], 
         function(tx,results){
             console.error("Successfully Emptied");
         },
         function(tx,error){
             console.error("Error: " + error.message);
         }
     )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed, it was a silly mistake. I was calling

> toast('Deleted');

function which was not yet defined therefore the statement was failing.
Sorry for my bad and thanks for helping.